# Poliigon Models in Blender

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

Does anyone have experience working with **Polligon Models** in **Blender**? I use their textures and they are great. I just downloaded the Tree stump 003

https://www.poliigon.com/search/tree-stump-
It uses 5 million faces and I believe is **bogging down my computer**. Am I doing something wrong or would this model bog down any machine?

**My System** i7 64 gb ram 1 tb SDD Nvidia 3060 TI comes to a halt when using these.

Comment: Holy moly: 5 *million* faces?!  ... is my reaction.  you may want to try (Edit mode) to Mesh >> Clean_Up >> Decimate, to a ratio of say 0.2 or lower.  Ratio of 0.5 will still leave you with a horrendous number (2.5m?) of faces.  If I try to download the 8k free one it's a 1.8 gb zip file ::: huge!!

Comment: Thanks for the verification. I did try the decimate modifier but it didn't really help enough. Ended up with a different model. I Sent their customer service a note letting them know the issues.

Comment: https://youtu.be/qCzncv0ISaE?t=69